# bundle exec rake test throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

Hello there I am new to rail. I am following railstutorial.org by Michael Hartl. I am stuck in chapter 4, Listing 4.5:
when i hit `$ bundle exec rake test` it showing some different result than it supposed to show as per tutorial. 
Note :I am using Ubuntu 15.10 as a platform.

Result when i hit `$ bundle exec rake test`

```
  /home/shyambhimani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/minitest_reporter_plugin.rb:8:in `block in plugin_minitest_reporter_init': undefined method `add_defaults' for #<Guard::Minitest::Reporter:0x005580a1496930> (NoMethodError)
  from /home/shyambhimani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/minitest_reporter_plugin.rb:6:in `each'
  from /home/shyambhimani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/minitest_reporter_plugin.rb:6:in `plugin_minitest_reporter_init'
  from /home/shyambhimani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:74:in `block in init_plugins'
  from /home/shyambhimani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:72:in `each'
  from /home/shyambhimani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:72:in `init_plugins'
  from /home/shyambhimani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:123:in `run'
  from /home/shyambhimani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:56:in `block in autorun'
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all',
                                              'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      page_title + " | " + base_title
    end
  end
end
```

static_pages_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get :help
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get :about
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end
end
```

test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical
  # order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '4.2.6'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Please guide me how can i get rid of the error.

Comment: Have you considered doing what the error message asks you to do?

Comment: I am not able to understand what error message says. Can you elaborate what are the steps i should take ? @MarsAtomic

Comment: show your fixtures file

Comment: How does your `Gemfile` look like?

Comment: I added Gemfile. I upgraded rails to 4.2.6. @spickermann

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are using [RubyDep](https://github.com/e2/ruby_dep), a tool that helps you to avoid insecure Ruby versions. RubyDep tells you in the first line:

> RubyDep: WARNING: your Ruby has security vulnerabilities! Please upgrade! (...)

Looking at the path (`.../.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/...`) of the other lines of the stacktrace it looks like you are using Ruby version 2.2.3, installed with [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

And RubyDep is right: There is a [known vulnerability in Ruby `2.2.3`](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-7551).

There are [newer versions of Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/) available. You could upgrade to the latest `2.2.x` version (or the latest `2.3.x`). I suggest to upgrade to `2.2.5`, because I'm do not know if the tutorial is compatible with `2.3.x`.

To upgrade Ruby to a newer version with `rbenv` follow this steps (I suppose you used [`brew`](http://brew.sh/) to install `rbenv`):

```
brew update               # update to the latest brew version
brew upgrade ruby-build   # update Ruby version library
brew upgrade rbenv        # update rbenv
rbenv install 2.2.5       # install Ruby 2.2.5
```

Set 2.2.5 to you default Ruby version:

```
rbenv global 2.2.5
```

Update your Rails application to use this Ruby version. To do so check the following files (if they exist, they might be hidden) and change the Ruby version in that files:

```
.ruby-version
Gemfile
```

You might want to check in your applications root that you are using the updated version of Ruby:

```
ruby -v                   # should return `ruby 2.2.5p...`
```

Last step is to reinstall gems:

```
gem install bundler
bundler install
```

Was the update successful?

```
bundle exec rake test
```

Comment: @ShyamBhimani it looks like you must have upgraded your gems when you upgraded your Ruby, otherwise it's not possible that the above stacktrace went away.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
export RUBY_DEP_GEM_SILENCE_WARNINGS=1
```

If that doesn't work, try to install an older version of Guard or Minitest.

```
gem list Minitest

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

minitest (5.8.4, 5.7.0, 5.6.1, 4.7.5)
```

Use `gem help install` to see how to install a different version than the latest.

Sometimes a new version has bugs and is incompatible with an old Ruby or Rails version.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

It looks like your actual problem is your version of minitest-reporters. Digging through both the guard-minitest source and minitest-reporters, it looks like minitest-reporters used to invoke methods `io` and `add_defaults` on all of the minitest plugins that were being used. From the looks of it, minitest itself never actually defined an `add_defaults` method on any of their Reporters. It looks like the minitest-reporters gem itself defines a bunch of custom reporters that have `add_defaults` defined on them, but it seems to blow up on anything that inherits directly from the minitest gem itself as guard-minitest does.

### The solution

Fortunately, it looks like the minitest-reporters gem actually fixed this as a bug without saying anything about it, specifically in [this](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters/commit/b1e7d19c5dcddaa7c5350345dea3f969c0b54f82) commit. Notice the call to `respond_to?` on line 47, that should fix this particular stacktrace you're getting.

What this means is that you should upgrade your version of minitest-reporters. It looks like the first version that has this fix in it is minitest-reporters 1.1.2. So you should modify your Gemfile to use at least that version.

### Some advice

As general ruby practice though, especially with things like testing, there's really no reason to pin your versions in your Gemfile. What I would do is just remove the version for minitest-reporters from the Gemfile altogether and check in your Gemfile.lock to rely on particular installed versions. It'll make updating your dependencies easier.

## Edit

Sorry, looks like I was slightly wrong about where this was fixed. Found the real commit, it's here:

https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters/commit/8e3a8e0a195e31d97a35e4d8b7d1f05cb833ce93

It looks like the version this was introduced in was 1.0.11. So your Gemfile just needs to use at least that instead, as in:

```
gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.11'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Gemfile, just remove the specific version next to minitest_reporters gem and run bundle install - minitest_reporters added the fix in a later version than 1.0.5.